# Using preg_replace to format

Tags: php, sql, string, preg-replace

Having trouble with pattern and replacement. How can I make the replacement echo a final product such as

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`person`, `file`) VALUES
('test','test'),
('test2','test2'),
('test3','test3');
```

I am trying to insert the string into SQL but I need to format the current string below to do so, and I need to have the last part of the string **test3:test3** or whatever the text may be to close the SQL pattern **('test3','test3');**

```
<?php
$string = 'test:test test2:test2 test3:test3';
$pattern = '';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Also, can it also have a string such as this? `'test@test.com:test test2:test2'` whereas the email will be before the colon at ALL times.

Comment: This is almost certainly an inappropriate use of regular expressions.  What will you do when a value contains a colon, a single quote, a newline or any other number of characters that carry special meaning in sql?

Comment: There won't be other data. I made sure of that. It's strictly biased to test:test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$string = 'test:test test2:test2 test3:test3';
$patterns = array("/([^\s:]+):([^\s:]+)/", "/\s++\(/");
$replacements = array("('$1', '$2')", ", (");
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`person`, `file`) VALUES ' . preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string) . ';';
echo $sql . "\n";
```

An explanation:

```
Regex 1
  ([^\s:]+)   # match one or more chars other than white space chars and colons and store it in group 1
  :           # match a colon 
  ([^\s:]+)   # match one or more chars other than white space chars and colons and store it in group 2 
Replacement 1
  (           # insert a '('
  '$1'        # insert what is matched in group 1 and surround it with single quotes
  ,           # insert ', '
  '$2'        # insert what is matched in group 2 and surround it with single quotes
  )           # insert a ')'

Regex 2
  \s++        # match one or more white space chars
  \(          # match a '('
Replacement 2
  , (         # insert ', ('
```

Comment: @Bart Thanks so much. I'm so inexperienced with this, I have been fooling around with it for an hour now.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure you understand what you're doing (read my explanation carefully).